# Python network manager class using exec()

Tags: python, pyqt, python-requests

I wanted to make a small self-integrated API for my PyQt5 application.

This class is a tiny chunk of the whole project:

```py
class NyvoNetHunterRequestManager(QObject):
    
    sending_request = pyqtSignal()
    request_sent = pyqtSignal()
    
    failed_to_send = pyqtSignal()
    
    received_valid_response = pyqtSignal()
    received_invalid_response = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, url: str, data: Dict, headers: Dict, method: Literal["get", "post", "put", "delete"]):
        self.url = url
        self.data = data
        self.headers = headers
        self.method = method
        
        super(QObject, self).__init__()
        
    def fire(self) -> str:
        self.sending_request.emit()
        
        current_method_name = self.method
        
        try:
            exec(
            f"global _BACKENDRESPOND; _BACKENDRESPOND = requests.{current_method_name}(url='{self.url}', data={self.data}, headers={self.headers})"
            )
            
            global _BACKENDRESPOND
            self.response = _BACKENDRESPOND
            del _BACKENDRESPOND
            
            self.request_sent.emit()
            
        except ConnectionError:
            self.failed_to_send.emit()
            return
            
        if self.response.ok:
            self.received_valid_response.emit()
            return self.response
        
        self.received_invalid_response.emit()
        return self.response
            
        
    @property
    def url(self):
        return self._url
        
    @url.setter
    def url(self, _url):
        if not isinstance(_url, str):
            url_argument_type = type(_url).__name__
            raise ValueError(f"Expected argument type passed for the parameter( url ): ( str ) | Not ( {url_argument_type}")
        
        url_is_invalid = not is_valid_url(_url)
        if url_is_invalid:
            raise TypeError("That is not a valid url.")
            
            
        self._url = _url
        
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data
        
    @data.setter
    def data(self, _data):
        if not isinstance(_data, dict):
            data_argument_type = type(_data).__name__
            raise ValueError(
            f"Expected argument type passed for the parameter ( data ): ( dict ) | Not: ( {data_argument_type} )"
            )
            
            
        self._data = _data
            
    @property
    def headers(self):
        return self._headers
        
    @headers.setter
    def headers(self, _headers):
        if not isinstance(_headers, dict):
            headers_argument_type = type(_headers).__name__
            raise ValueError(f"Expected argument type passed for the parameter ( headers ): ( dict ) | Not: ( {headers_argument_type} )")
            
        
        self._headers = _headers
        
    @property
    def method(self):
        return self._method
        
    @method.setter
    def method(self, _method):
        available_http_methods = ["get", "post", "put", "delete"]
        
        if not isinstance(_method, str):
            method_argument_type = type(_method).__name__
            raise ValueError(f"Expected argument types passed for the parameter ( method ): ( str ) | Not: {method_argument_type}")
            
        if not _method in available_http_methods:
            raise TypeError("That is not a valid http method.")
            
            
        self._method = _method


module_is_runned_directly = __name__ == "__main__"
if module_is_runned_directly:
    raise DirectRunError("Database modules are not intended to run directly, they are produced for improt usage only.")
```

I have used the `exec` function because I needed the HTTP method to be passed as an argument, and I also wanted to avoid making encapsulated methods for each HTTP function.

The main idiomatic question is: **Is using the `exec()` function in this way actually safe?**

Comment: Do you have any tests or example usage?  It seems a bit strange to call this a "network manager" when all it seems to do is store details of (a subset of) HTTP transactions.

Comment: What are you doing with the response? Is it always guaranteed to be JSON (or some other content type)?

Comment: You have good sense to be very wary of `exec`. It's practically never the right answer.

Comment: What would happen if either `self.url`, `self.data`, or `self.headers` contain a `'`? What if one of them is equal to `'); import os; os.system('malware.exe'); ('`?

Answer (score 10):

`sending_request` is not a great name for an event; similar to your other signals, it should describe something that happened i.e. `request_started`.

Add parameter names and types to your signals where applicable. The failure signals should receive contextual information, and the valid response signal should receive the payload (or perhaps the `Response` object).

Provide sane defaults for your `__init__` parameters. For instance, `get` is overwhelmingly the most common method.

Stop using `Dict`. Update Python and use `dict`.

Instead of keeping the broken-out request parameters `url`, `method` etc. on the class, just prepare a request. Don't allow mutation of these parameters. Delete every one of your accessor methods. If you need a different request, construct a different "manager".

Don't use `exec`! And *especially* don't tie this into a non-reentrant global variable. And *especially especially* don't allow arbitrary code execution by directly concatenating the parameter strings.

Don't silently swallow exceptions. Re-throw them.

Delete your `module_is_runned_directly`; it isn't helping.

Consider upgrading from PyQt5 to PyQt6.

You should be using a `requests.Session`. Internally, calling any of the top-level methods like `requests.get` spins up a single-use session, but you can do better. There should usually be one session per domain name (or, sometimes, set of related domain names within one organization). Separately, you *need* a session to be able to manually send prepared requests, as I demonstrate in the first code blob.

More broadly: this is in a cursed middle ground. It's a wrapper with some events that might seem useful - but only if the method is asynchronous, and it isn't asynchronous. If you want to keep it synchronous, then... just delete everything and call `requests` directly. This is also over-broad boilerplate; it doesn't offer much beyond what requests already offers. It would be more useful if it spoke to the domain-specific HTTP operation, which you have not shown. (There's a decent chance that your code will never use a `delete` method.) But in another sense - if you wanted to keep it generic, it isn't broad enough. The list of methods isn't exhaustive; for instance there's also [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).

Since you're already drinking the Qt cool-aid, consider replacing requests with [QNetworkRequest](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtnetwork/qnetworkrequest.html). [It has plenty of signals.](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/api/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html)

### Example (requests)

Covering a subset of the above,

```py
from typing import Literal, Any

import requests
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtBoundSignal


class NyvoNetHunterRequestManager(QObject):
    __slots__ = 'request',

    request_started: pyqtBoundSignal = pyqtSignal()
    request_sent: pyqtBoundSignal = pyqtSignal()
    failed_to_send: pyqtBoundSignal = pyqtSignal(str, arguments=('reason',))
    received_valid_response: pyqtBoundSignal = pyqtSignal(str, arguments=('content',))
    received_invalid_response: pyqtBoundSignal = pyqtSignal(int, str, arguments=('code', 'reason'))

    def __init__(
        self,
        url: str,
        method: Literal['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'] = 'get',
        headers: dict[str, str] | None = None,
        data: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.request = requests.Request(
            method=method, url=url, headers=headers, data=data,
        ).prepare()
        super().__init__()

    def send(self, session: requests.Session) -> str:
        self.request_started.emit()

        try:
            with session.send(request=self.request, stream=True) as response:
                # Due to stream mode, will be sent before the full body is retrieved
                self.request_sent.emit()

                if response.ok:
                    self.received_valid_response.emit(response.text)
                    return response.text

                self.received_invalid_response.emit(response.status_code, response.reason)
                response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.HTTPError:
            raise
        except IOError as e:
            self.failed_to_send.emit(str(e))
            raise


def demo() -> None:
    def request_started() -> None:
        print('Request started.')
    def request_sent() -> None:
        print('Request sent.')
    def failed_to_send(reason: str) -> None:
        print('Failed to send:', reason)
    def received_valid_response(response: str) -> None:
        print('Received valid response:', response[:80], '...')
    def received_invalid_response(code: int, reason: str) -> None:
        print('Received invalid response:', code, reason)

    with requests.Session() as session:
        manager = NyvoNetHunterRequestManager(url=
            'https://google.com'  # Valid
            # 'https://invaliddomainname.wrong',  # IOError
            # 'https://google.com/invalidurlpath',  # 404
        )
        manager.request_started.connect(request_started)
        manager.request_sent.connect(request_sent)
        manager.failed_to_send.connect(failed_to_send)
        manager.received_valid_response.connect(received_valid_response)
        manager.received_invalid_response.connect(received_invalid_response)

        manager.send(session)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

### A word on `eval`

Don't `exec`, don't `eval`. Forget that those ever existed until about 15 years into your software development career. If there were a gun to your head and you were forced to use `eval` for this application (which, again, you absolutely shouldn't), a safer way would look like

```py
import requests


def request_eval(method: str, url: str) -> str:
    if not isinstance(method, str):
        raise TypeError('method must be str')
    if method.lower() not in {
        'get', 'put', 'post', 'delete',
        'head', 'options', 'connect', 'trace', 'patch',
    }:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid method "{method}"')

    code = compile(
        source='requests.' + method + '(url=url)',
        filename='dynamic_requests_call',
        mode='eval', dont_inherit=1,
    )
    empty_globals = {'__builtins__': {}}
    req_locals = {
        'requests': requests,
        'url': url,
        # ...other request parameters
    }
    response = eval(code, empty_globals, req_locals)
    return response.text


print(
    request_eval(
        method='get', url='https://google.com',
    )[:80], '...',
)
```

Observe the differences. We don't allow use of any built-ins or globals, we pass in locals via variable key-value pair and not string formatting, and we ban compiler flag inheritance.

### Dynamic import

For completeness, the following is a half-measure that you also shouldn't do, but is still a better idea than `eval`. It imports the requests library method based on name.

```py
import requests


def request_attr(method: str, url: str) -> str:
    if not isinstance(method, str):
        raise TypeError('method must be str')
    if method.lower() not in {
        'get', 'put', 'post', 'delete',
        'head', 'options', 'connect', 'trace', 'patch',
    }:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid method "{method}"')

    fun = getattr(requests, method)
    response = fun(url=url)
    return response.text


print(
    request_attr(
        method='get', url='https://google.com',
    )[:80], '...',
)
```

Comment: You can also get rid of checking if `method` is an instance of a string - because of the type being listed in the function, Python won't call the `request_attr()` function unless it gets two strings.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Thanks for the comment. That's not how type hints work - they're hints only; Python will do nothing in runtime to prevent the method from being called with nonsense. In this case since it's such a vulnerable operation, I want to reduce the amount of funny business possible.

Comment: Must be my IDE then... I thought it worked like a method signature.

Answer (score 10):

## You don't need to use `exec()`.

`requests` has a [`requests.request()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#requests.request) function that takes the name of the method as the first argument.  Use that.